# Analysizing MSMQ over HTTPS traffic using WireShark - not seeing POST

Tags: https, msmq, wireshark

I am troubleshooting an issue where MSMQ messages are stuck in an outbound queue (queue saying Waiting to Connect). In order to troubleshoot I am running WireShark to see exactly what is being pushed over the network interface.

I have run a WireShark trace and what I see seems to be a full SSLV3 handshake (generated from local MSMQ trying to connect to the server):

Client->Server - Client Hello

Server->Client - Server Hello

Client->Server - Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec

Server->Client - Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake

After these messages I was expecting to see a POST message with the client trying to push a message to the server, and some sort of response from the server but there is nothing. All I see between the client and server after the last Change Cipher Spec is a set of [ACK] and [SYN] messages before the next SSLV3 handshake. The specific messages are:

Client->Server - TCP - [FIN, ACK]

Server->Client - TCP - [ACK]

Server->Client - TCP - [FIN, ACK]

Client->Server - TCP - [ACK]

Client->Server - TCP - [SYN]

Server->Client - TCP - [SYN]

Client->Server - TCP - [ACK]

Then the handshake is repeated.

Should I not expect to see a POST message after the handshake? I know that MSMQ does an HTTP POST of the MSMQ messages when sent over HTTP so I was expecting this to show up as application data after the handshake.

Do I need to somehow configure WireShark to see these since it is over HTTPS?

Thanks

Comment: Quick test - browse to the HTTPS location of the queue (using IE, etc) to ensure the SSL is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you've followed the documentation to [decipher SSL using Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) (otherwise, you'll see the packets, but won't be able to look into their content). Note that to achieve this, you need the server's private key to be available to wireshark, otherwise anyone could decipher the SSL/TLS connection (and protecting against that is exactly the point of using SSL/TLS).

In addition, you may need to force your tools to use cipher suites that are considered less robust nowadays. Modern browsers, for example, tend to use Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman (DHE) cipher suites (unless explicitly configured not to). Wireshark won't be able to decipher an SSL connection that uses such a cipher suite.

Comment: It looks like, if you don't see any application data (even enciphered) after the handshake, there's a problem with the establishment of the connection (do you see the normal closure alerts at least?). It would help to see more from the server logs if you can.

Comment: I am not so much interested in seeing the decrypted information as I am to see that there is some sort of packet exchange taking place after the handshake, i.e. the Application Data exchanges as per the SSL spec.

Comment: Yes, you should see some Application Data if a POST was sent. You should also see some Alerts (perhaps encrypted) if the connection is closed (even if it's closed normally). Not seeing either may imply that the party that should send some data first "hangs" without sending anything (that would probably be the client, since it's the one that should make the request first when using HTTP).

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I was able to verify on another server that Application Data exchanges take place after the handshake when everything works as it should. How do I mark your question as the answer?

Comment: To accept an answer, there should be a tick symbol shape under the vote counter (if you look at other questions with an accepted answer, it's where the green tick is): clicking on it should turn it green.

Comment: @user469104 I have the same issue where the connect never completes over https.  did you identify the root cause on your server?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of SSL encryption is that information sent over the wire is encrypted, therefore, not visible. Personally, I would be very concerned if you could packet sniff SSL traffic. You *may* be able to configure wireshark to show more information over SSL than you are currently seeing, but you will never see the actual contents, such as POST.

Comment: So WireShark would not be able to show the packet exchanges even if only as 'Encrypted Data'? Right now I am seeing nothing after the handshake.

Comment: *If* it's a closed system and the private keys are available (eg. the OP is server admin and he has access to keys), then sniffer should be able to show SSL-protected traffic (also depends on sniffer, of course).